# If $aa \colon X$, what is one possible value of $aa$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Context: Introductory set theory

This is presumably a very simple question however I don't quite understand what is being asked here.

$$X = \{a,b\}$$

My understanding of the symbol $\colon$ is that it means "such that".

Given that definition of $\colon$, I interpret the question to mean "if $aa \colon X$". Does this mean the question is saying $aa = X$, or is there a different meaning here?

edit:

Full question exactly as written by the teacher:

Given $X = \{a, b\}$, show the following.

(b) if $aa \colon X$, one possible value of $aa$

Comment: I have added the full question exactly as written by the teacher.

Comment: Teacher talks nonsense.

Comment: I don't understand what is being asked either.  The question seems to make no sense at all.

Comment: Maybe your teacher gave a certain definition for ":" in the class (only to be used in his class to make things easier) different from the known definition ?

Comment: Please elaborate upto what you understand

Answer (score 1):

This looks like set theory taught in a philosophy course.
aa is weird notation for a variable.
aa:X means aa is X, has the property X.  For example, all d are X.
It is a misleading way to say aa is in the set X = {a,b}.
Consequently, if aa:X, then aa can be a or aa can be b.

Have I decoded the philosophy talk?
Please advise the teacher to limit her teaching of philosophy math to counting the number of angels that can dance on the head of a pin.

Answer (score 0):

I have consulted a teacher about this question and this is what I was told.

$aa : X ⇔ X$ takes value from $aa ⇔ X ∈ aa$

What we know about $aa$ is that it has *X* as one of its elements.

∴ One possible value of $aa$ is the set containing $X$ which is $\{X\}$